# How to add mailto behavior to HTTP response?

Tags: http, firefox

I want to use a HTTP 303 response to redirect to a mailto scheme URI.

This works for in Safari and Chrome but in Firefox i'm left with a blank page. I'm guessing the 303 response is rendered by Firefox while Safari and Chrome open the mailto URI in the background and leave the page as it was.

HTML page:

```
<a href="/mailto/joe">email joe</a>
```

Server response:

```
$ curl -i -X GET http://example.com/mailto/joe
HTTP/1.0 303 See Other
Location: mailto:joe@example.com
Content-Length: 0
Server: Werkzeug/0.9.4 Python/2.7.5
Date: Wed, 05 Mar 2014 09:19:05 GMT
```

How can I get Firefox to behave like Safari and Chrome?

Comment: report a bug to Mozilla?

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was a bug, will do if nothing helpful turns up.